# Export all http requests on a specific page to txt/csv

Tags: debugging, http, google-chrome, firefox

I use SIEGE to test my web server performance. For a more realistic test the best way to go would be to  have SIEGE hit the web page (website.com/our-company) and all static assets (.css, .js, .png, .jpg). Everything that you see on the firefox / chrome debbuing tools, except of course from resources loaded from external servers (cdn.facebook, apis.google.com).

I am running several tests so it is a pain to manually collect all asset urls. Is there a tool that I can use to load a web page and export the url for everything that was loaded?

**This is firefox debugging. If I could export this to txt or csv, it would be perfect.**
[image]

I tried CURL on debian CLI but I am no experct. Any tool will help, it does't have to be a plugin of Firefox / Chrome.

Best regards.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Chrome you can export these data to a [HAR](http://httparchive.org/about.php#harfile) file (it's JSON based) in one click. Go to "Network", right click and choose "Save as HAR with content".

[image: Save as HAR with Content option in DevTools]

Comment: Thanks, but thats not what I need. Maybe I did not understand you correctly. I need a list of all css, js and img that is being requested on a page in order to be able to simulate a full page load with SIEGE. I was able to get that with livehttpheaders + some excel. Very easy. Best regards.

Comment: HAR file contains all URLs that were loaded + all headers + all load times. Since it's a JSON file you can easily extract what you need.

Comment: Konrad,Thans for your help, but that seems harder then the other tools (like livehttpheader). Maybe I am not getting you. How do you suggest I extract the URLS from HAR? Using which tool? Best regards.

Comment: Perhaps a bit late but in case someone else is exploring a solution, I found this. Haven't tried it yet but give it a shot.
http://www.yamamoto.com.ar/blog/?p=201

Comment: http://www.yamamoto.com.ar/blog/?p=201 link is not reachable.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a free command line application to convert HAR files to CSV. Hope it helps.

http://www.yamamoto.com.ar/blog/?p=201

EDIT: added the project to GitHub:

https://github.com/spcgh0st/HarTools

Answer (score 1):

On Windows you could use HttpWatch to do this with the free Basic Edition in IE or Firefox:

http://www.httpwatch.com/download/

The CSV export function will export the URLs and other fields to a CSV file.

** Disclaimer: This was posted by Simtec Limited the makers of HttpWatch **

Answer (score 1):

Had the same requirement of exporting HAR files from Chrome DevTools or Firebug to do load testing with siege. Additionally, I wanted to replay POST requests too.

Choose one of these solutions:

- hardy @ https://github.com/nbibler/hardy - ruby script
- har2siege @ https://gist.github.com/photopresentr/7974747 - node.js (my script)

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind.

Just fond out the very nive LiveHtttpHeaders extension for firefox.

Best regards.

Comment: Hmm, why did you accept the other answer then? Also, what does LiveHttpHeaders do that the Chrome export cannot?

Answer (score 0):

As you guys know, the HAR file format is a JSON file. So... I looked for a JSON to CSV converter and found this:

https://json-csv.com/

This worked for my HAR file that I got from GTmetrix.com. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

You can **Export all Http requests** from **Chrome Developer console** by going to the **Network tab**

- select one of the requests in Network Tab
- press Right Mouse Button
- from PopUp menu select Copy -> Copy all as Har (Curl/Har/etc)
- paste into file

[image]