# How to export response bodies only using chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

[image]

I'm working with a website using chrome. I want to grab only the responses to certain requests (which I am filtering for in the screenshot). Previously I tried to [Export all http requests on a specific page to txt/csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19246599/export-all-http-requests-on-a-specific-page-to-txt-csv) , so I see that you can get a har file with a lot of unneeded info, but I would like just grab just the resonse bodies. Is this possible using devtools or an extension?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const re = /\/stackoverflow/
const result = HAR.log.entries.filter(entiry => re.test(entiry.request.url))
console.log(result)
```

That's all you need.
`HAR` - your data with

> a lot of unneeded info

`re` - your filter

Note the `/` in the regexp. The filter in the DevTools doesn't take the domain into account.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but where do you run this code. Somehow within devtools or after export of the larger HAR file?

Comment: You can 1) export har-file, 2) open it with a text-editor, 3) copy it's content, 4) write in the devtools console `HAR = ` 5) paste the content of har-file copied earlier, press <Enter> (that will create a HAR object in the console) 6) copy&paste the above code in the console 7) run it.

But if you know JS/node.js it's preferably to open exported HAR in a node.js script